# Filter Condition is not working in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in which I have some records. I am passing one filter condition but it is not giving me correct result. Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Example:

df:

```
vendor       programdate
medforce     3/3/2020
decile       4/3/2020
medforce     8/5/2020
decile       7/23/2020
decile       3/27/2020
```

I am passing filter condition given below:

```
df1 = df.query("programdate > '3/3/2020'")
```

It is printing all the records. It should to print only filtered records. Can you please help me?

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to check the datatype of the column, so you would run:

```
df.dtype
```

And it would output the result: "object"

Now you want to change the datatype of the "programdate" column and you'd do so by running:

```
df["programdate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["programdate"])
```

Now that it is in a datetime you can filter the dates by running:

```
df.query("programdate > '3/3/2020'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df1 = df[df.programdate > '3/3/2020']
```

Make sure "programdate" is a datetime stamp

Comment: not getting the result. I have to use only df.query().

Answer (score 0):

The `df.query()` code works for me. What are your data types for each column?

Comment: dtype = str. this i have given

Comment: You're not going to get the answer you expect if you are filtering dates but they have a string data type. As @Jorge says, you're data should be in the datatime format. You can do this as follows: `df['programdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['programdate])`. Then when you run your query `df.query("programdate > '3/3/2020'")` you will get the data that you expect.

Comment: Now I got my expected result. Thank you for your suggestion.